# What is measure of unit circle?

Tags: measure-theory

How to find  measure of unit circle?

I think that it can be covered by open balls of very small radius and hence its measure is zero.

But when i  prove the existence of a non-measurable set; it is given that neither it has measure zero nor infinite measure.Why is this true?

Note: i am new to this topic;so please excuse me if the question is easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, if for every $\epsilon > 0$ you can cover the unit circle by open balls whose total area is at most $\epsilon$, then the unit circle has measure zero.

It's not enough that every individual ball is very small: $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be covered by open balls of as small a radius as you wish. What's important is that their *total* area is small. From a different point of view, you are interested in the minimum number $N_\delta$ of open balls of radius $\delta$ needed to cover the unit circle. If $N_\delta \ll 1/\delta^2$ then the measure is zero. In this case in fact $N_\delta = \Theta(1/\delta)$, since the unit circle has dimension one.

Comment: what is $N_\delta=$ ?

Comment: I have got your point except the last line which I have pointed

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the word "minimum". The quantity $N_\delta$ is how many balls of radius $\delta$ you need to cover your shape (in this case, the unit circle).

Comment: What is $O(\dfrac{1}{\delta})$

Comment: This is asymptotic notation. The notation $N_\delta \ll 1/\delta^2$ means that $\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{N_\delta}{1/\delta^2} = 0$. The notation $N_\delta = \Theta(1/\delta)$ means that there exist $\delta_0,c,C>0$ such that $c/\delta \leq N_\delta \leq C/\delta$ for all $0 < \delta < \delta_0$.

Comment: one final question sir how did you see that $N_\delta$ is so and what is meant by dimension of circle?

Comment: I didn't explain why $N_\delta = \Theta(1/\delta)$ but you can try to prove it yourself. If $N_\delta = \Theta(1/\delta^D)$ for some shape then we say that (by definition) the shape has dimension $D$. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension. There are other definitions of dimension, such as the popular Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: You don't need the concept of dimension here. You only need to prove that $N_\delta \ll 1/\delta^2$. In fact, it's not so difficult to prove that $N_\delta = O(1/\delta)$, that is, that $N_\delta < C/\delta$ for some constant $C > 0$. Give it a shot.

Comment: sorry I am not getting anything to start with

Comment: Well, keep thinking. The only way to make progress is to solve exercises on your own.

Comment: ok If I can; I will be back with my solution ;till then good bye;I will accept this when i am convinced ;now only an upvote for you